# Firebase set data in realtime database is getting timed out golang

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am using firebase go lang admin sdk to insert data in realtime database.
I am just using

`database.NewRef(nodeName).Set(ctx, userData)`
for ctx, I am using context with timeout with 15 seconds of timeout.

This functionality was working fine and I was getting response in 1-3 seconds. But suddenly I have started to get error with request timeout as was not getting response from firebase in 15 seconds.

So just want to know, if there is any mechanism by which I can check log on firebase that why this request is taking much time.

Comment: Well, this question is not related to "Go",  so please be specific to tag. for your question [read her](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/cloud-audit-logging/firebase-management)

Comment: I used, firebase golang sdk thas why I used "Go"